# NLog does not create log file

Tags: asp.net, nlog

I've just created an empty ASP.NET 5 web appliction and I want to use NLog for my logs. So far I've successfully installed NLog and created a public static Logger in the Startup class. In my application folder I've created the NLog.config file with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets>
        <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="file.txt" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logfile" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

In the Configure method of Startup class I'm trying to log some data with the following lines of code:

```
logger.Warn("foo1");
logger.Debug("foo2");
```

The project builds successfully but after running it I don't see any file.txt whatsoever.

Comment: Quick setup is at https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging

Answer (score 1):

I have found a possible solution. After creating an ASP.NET 5 empty project you can do the following:

1) Open the Startup.cs file and add the following usings:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using NLog.Framework.Logging;
```

Notice that in order to add the second using you have to modify the package.json file by adding the following dependency:

```
"NLog.Framework.logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
```

2) In the startup.cs file you must modify the signature of the "Configure" method by adding the arguments ihe and ilf. So it will eventually look like this.

```
Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment ihe, ILoggerFactory ilf)
```

The arguments ihe and ifg are to be used in this way:

```
ilf.AddNLog();
ihe.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config");
ILogger logger = ilf.CreateLogger(GetType().Namespace);
logger.LogInformation("i am nlog bye bye");
```

3) In the project folder, that is not wwwroot but its parent folder, add a file and call it "nlog.config". It can be filled with the following contnent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Warn"
      internalLogFile="c:\temp\internal.txt">


  <!-- define various log targets -->
  <targets>
    <!-- write logs to file -->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="allfile" fileName="c:\temp\nlog-all-${shortdate}.log"
                 layout="${longdate}|${logger}|${uppercase:${level}}|${message} ${exception}" />

    <target xsi:type="File" name="ownFile" fileName="c:\temp\nlog-own-${shortdate}.log"
              layout="${longdate}|${logger}|${uppercase:${level}}|${message} ${exception}" />

    <target xsi:type="Null" name="blackhole" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <!--All logs, including from Microsoft-->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="allfile" />

    <!--Skip Microsoft logs and so log only own logs-->
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="blackhole" final="true" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="ownFile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Now if you run the project and go to C:\temp you will see two files: "nlog-all-*.log" and "nlog-own-*.log". In the second file you'll see the message "i am nlog bye bye"

Answer (score 0):

Provide full path for log file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <!-- 
  See http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Configuration_file 
  for information on customizing logging rules and outputs.
   -->
  <targets>
    <!-- add your targets here -->
    <target name="asyncFile" xsi:type="AsyncWrapper">
      <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="C:\Log.txt" layout="${longdate} ${callsite} ${level} ${message} ${newline}" />
    </target>
    <!--
    <target xsi:type="File" name="f" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />
    -->
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <!-- add your logging rules here -->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="asyncFile" />
    <!--
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="f" />
    -->
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the NLogConfiguration which i had used and it's absoulty working Fine

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" autoReload="true">
        <targets >
    <target xsi:type="File" name="logfile"
            fileName="${basedir}/logs/YourFileName.log"
            layout="${longdate} ${level:uppercase=true:padding=5} ${gdc:item=hostname} ${gdc:item=useremail} (${logger} - ${mdc:item=actionname})  ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}"
            archiveEvery="Day"
            archiveFileName ="${basedir}/logs/YourFileName.${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm}.{#}.log"
            archiveNumbering ="Sequence"
            maxArchiveFiles="30"
            fileAttributes="Compressed">
    </target>
       </targets>
       <rules>
       <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="logfile">
      </logger>
      </rules>
    </nlog>
```

and on server side

```
public class YourClassName
{
   private static Logger log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

  public void YourMethodName()
    {
      try
        {
          log.Info("Success");
        }
        catch(Exception Ex)
        {
         log.Info("Exception"+ex);
        }
       } 
   }
```

Comment: Yes I've done that. But have you put it in the Startup class?